# Degenerate root finding problem: get the first value for which f(x)>0

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, optimization, scipy

Given a function *f(x)* that is zero for all values *x* less than a critical value *c*, and non-zero for values *x>c*.

I want to approximate the critical value *c* using an optimization method. Because the function *f(x)* is expensive, I want to compute it as few times as possible. Therefore, computing *f(x)* for a predefined list of values *x* is not viable.

Think of a function like the following one, with critical point *a=1.4142*

```py
def func(x):
    return max(x**2 - 2, 0) if x > 0 else 0
```

[image]

I would have implemented this using some custom bisection function. However, I was wondering if this "degenerate" root finding problem can be solved using existing functions in SciPy or NumPy. I have experimented with [`scipy.optimize.root_scalar`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root_scalar.html). However, it does not seem to support functions like the one above.

```py
from scipy.optimize import root_scalar
root_scalar(func, bracket=[-6, 8])
# Yields an error: f(a) and f(b) must have different signs.
```

Comment: With no other assumptions, you need to use a binary search.  If you assume that the function is, as here, twice differentiable on the right, then you can code up something more efficient. But it will have to be coded specially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically speaking, everywhere that x < 1.414 in that function is a root. If you want to use a root finder, you need to make it a valid root-finding problem. I suggest subtracting a very small value from the output of your function:

```
from scipy.optimize import root_scalar
import math
wrapper = lambda func: lambda *args: func(*args) - math.ulp(0)
root_scalar(wrapper(func), bracket=[-6, 8])
```

This works by subtracting one ULP (Unit in Last Place, the smallest value you can add or subtract) from your function. This makes it strictly negative for all x < 1.414 and strictly positive for all x > 1.414. On a computer with 64-bit floating point math, that means it's subtracting 5*10<sup>-324</sup> from each result, which very slightly moves the position of the root, but not much.

Comment: This is elegant and works well on my computer. Do you think this solution is portable to other systems?

Comment: Yes. If you run it on a system with less precise floating point math, then `math.ulp(0)` will be bigger, which compensates for that.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to present a "custom" bisect method that works for the presented example. However, I still recommend using the accepted answer.

```py
def bisect(func, x_min, x_max, x_func=None,
           tol=None, iter_max=None, **kwargs):
    y_min = func(x_min, **kwargs)
    if y_min > 0:
        msg = "Warning: no solution as y_min>0, with x_min=%f."
        print(msg % x_min)
        return x_min
    y_max = func(x_max, **kwargs)
    if y_max <= 0:
        msg = "Warning: no solution as y_max<=0, with x_max=%f."
        print(msg % x_max)
        return x_max
    if tol is None and iter_max is None:
        tol = 1e-7
    if x_func is None:
        x_func = lambda x0, x1: (x1+x0)/2
    
    from itertools import count, islice
    x_last = np.infty
    for cnt in islice(count(), iter_max):
        x_new = x_func(x_min, x_max)
        y_new = func(x_new, **kwargs)
        if y_new<=0:
            x_min = x_new
        else:
            x_max = x_new
        if (tol is not None) and abs(x_last - x_new) < tol:
            break
        x_last = x_new
    return x_min if y_new>0 else x_max

def func(x):
    return max(x**2 - 2, 0) if x > 0 else 0

ret = bisect(func, x_min=-6, x_max=8)
print(ret)
```

Interestingly, the performance of `bisect()` seems better than the `root_scalar` approach for this basic type of function `func(x)`. But I expect this advantage to vanish for more complex functions.

```py
%timeit bisect(func, x_min=-6, x_max=8, iter_max=None, tol=1e-7)
# 46.3 µs ± 1.96 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

%timeit root_scalar(wrapper(func), bracket=[-6, 8], xtol=1e-7)
# 84.6 µs ± 6.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

# Test that the results are equivalent:
x1 = bisect(func, x_min=-6, x_max=8, iter_max=None, tol=1e-7)
x2 = root_scalar(wrapper(func), bracket=[-6, 8], xtol=1e-7).root
assert abs(x2-x1) < 1e-7
# 2.9078300656237843e-08
```